# How do I find minerals on a planet?

Tags: space-engineers

I've started the "Star System" world template in Survival mode and landed my atmospheric lander in a mountain valley near a lake.

Now I am looking for resources to build a base, but so far I had no luck. I walked around my landing site and dug a 50m deep mining shaft, but no mineral location would appear on the hud.

Where and how should I look for minerals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Ore Detector to find ores in its detection range and fly/ride around the planet.

An other thing you can do is find "dark spots" like these: [image: Dark Spots]

They will show up when there are ores near the surface. (Screenshot burrowed from Reddit)